knex: use common knex object to switch schema ".withSchema"
I have a multitenant environment where I maintain different schemas for different clients.
To manage this setup I have a utility that returns me a knex object based on the identifier in the request. This knex object is helpful in several different ways.
This setup has a flaw as every time a request comes it creates a new knex instance, this is a problem in long run.
So what I was exploring is to use a common knex object and switch the schema based on request. .withSchema is helpful in this case.
But the .withSchema returns a QueryBuilder Object and this causes my connection to loose several utitliy methods for example .raw, .fn.now(), .transaction
Is there a way I can return the knex object with the schema changes?
